# Javascript removeAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, dom

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-cart').removeAttribute("class")
```

Please help !!! I need to remove the attribute title on document load. Its not working for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does not return an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). Instead, it's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-cart')[0].removeAttribute("class");
```

Comment: Not that this will only work for the first element in the list that has the class `btn-cart`.